# Laravel random logout

Tags: php, laravel, session

I am currently working in a local laravel project using the file session driver.
Unfortunately my user session randomly ends with no pattern what so ever sometimes after logging in,sometimes when sending a post method other times with get methods and i have had times i log out only hours after the Login (all a of these cases with active usage so i don't thing that it because of the session expiring) 
I have also verified the log for errors but non of the present errors belonged to any session.
I have already tried the following:

- Deleting current session files;
- Changing to database sessions;
- Increasing the session lifetime from the default 120 to 2400;
- Changing the lottery numbers to improbable probabilities like
  1,100000000;

My current laravel version is 5.4.23.
Thank you all in advance

Comment: Do you have multiple laravel projects that you are accessing?

Comment: i am at the moment only accessing this laravel project but i have accessed different projects before i am accessing a slim project at the same time

Comment: Well, the first thing that came to my mind was you had a cookie conflict.  If you're using the same domain (I.E. localhost) for every project, your session ID could be overwritten.

Comment: @Devon is right. It happens when you are working on multiple laravel projects and their session_name fields are same.

Comment: i am using 127.0.0.1:8000 for laravel and 127.0.0.1:1111 for a slim restful api that i believe doesnt use sessions

Comment: the only thing that the computer has been used for the last few days has been the before mentioned domains for the project in question